# Make MacBook Pro as if there is no notch

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I'm wondering whether to buy a MacBook Pro and my main issue is with the notch so I'm wondering whether it's possible to make the screen as in older Macs.

I don't mean turning the Menu Bar black or making some app show below the notch. I've seen solutions for this and it doesn't seem to work for all apps (eg. Finder).

I want to hide the dead pixels and not lose my touchpad pointer behind the notch. If there is a way to disable the top pixels (top 74 pixels), this will have the added benefit of fixing the screen resolution (8x5 instead of 756x491).

(As to why the notch bothers me, here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3C5lhYJa9o) for more context.)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "eg Finder".  I have a 2021 MBP and Finder stays below the notch, even in full-screen mode.  I don't lose any of the Finder window behind the notch.

Comment: @fsb I mean the menu bar stays below the notch.

Comment: Ok, I understand better now that you're concerned about losing menu items.  I was referencing the window staying below the notch.  I don't have extra menu items on Finder so they don't even come close to the notch.

Comment: On a 'non-notch' Mac, you still lose your menulets on the right-hand side if an app has too many menus. So no change there. It's possible that unnecessary (!) things like iStat Menus might need an update not to go behind the notch. It's likely there's not the fix you want, so I'd recommend making peace with it, and buying the MBP, which is a whole lot of awesome.

Comment: @benwiggy It's a change in frequency. Firstly, there is less space until the menus overflow and secondly, application developers did not account for this possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to disable the notch by changing the screen resolution (as suggested by nicolas2008). I found a swift script that lists available resolutions and allows to select one. I had to make a couple of modifications (to enable retina scaling) so here is my version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

let display = CGMainDisplayID()
let query : [String: Any] = [kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes as String : kCFBooleanTrue]
guard let dmodes = CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes(display, query as CFDictionary) as? [CGDisplayMode] else {exit(1)}

let argv = CommandLine.arguments
if argv.count == 2 {
    guard let modeNum = Int(argv[1]) else {
        fputs("mode num should be integer but: \(argv[1])\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    if modeNum < 0 || dmodes.count <= modeNum {
        fputs("mode num should be in 0-\(dmodes.count - 1) but: \(argv[1])\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    let config = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGDisplayConfigRef?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    defer {config.deallocate()}
    CGBeginDisplayConfiguration(config)
    CGConfigureDisplayWithDisplayMode(config.pointee, display, dmodes[modeNum], nil)
    CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration(config.pointee, CGConfigureOption.permanently)
}

if let current = CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode(display) {
    print(String(format: "current: %5d x %-5d @ %f", current.width, current.height, current.refreshRate))
    for (i, dmode) in dmodes.enumerated() {
        let mark = dmode.ioDisplayModeID == current.ioDisplayModeID ? "(current)" : ""
        print(String(format: "mode %2d: %5d x %-5d @ %f \(mark)", i, dmode.width, dmode.height, dmode.refreshRate))
    }
}
```

compile with: `swiftc hidenotch.swift`

Run without arguments to list resolutions.

Find the desired resolution (for 14" MacBookPro use `1512 x 945   @ 120.000000`).

Run with with the mode number of the resolution as argument - e.g. `./hidenotch 101`.

Comment: Great answer. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Two hours after your question, Apple released macOS Monterey 12.1 which has a fix for some notch display issues.

After upgrading to Monterey 12.1, you'll find that the menu bar items (on the right hand side) won't get obscured by the notch.

You might want to reconsider loosing the extra screen real estate now that at least some of these issues have been fixed.

If you still want to do as per your question, you can actually do that using this work around:

For the few programs that do not yet properly support the notch and have issues with too many menu items - Apple created a "[work around feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212842)": Open Finder, find the app, right-click and select `Get Info`. In the small window that opens, enable `Scale to fit below built-in camera`.

Now when you open that app, the menu bar will appear below the notch. This goes not only for that particular app, but for all the apps in the same Space (if you're not using Spaces, then it is simply for all your apps).

So you could simply consider enabling that work-around for a program you always have open (for example a browser) - and your menubar will be located as you requested.

Comment: Is the option "Scale to fit below built-in camera" available for system apps (like Finder)? I suppose in any case it could be set with `defaults write com.apple.finder <something> -string YES`.

Answer (score 2):

SwitchResX.
Just change 1512x982 HiDPI 3:2 to 1512x945 HiDPI 16:10 (or any other resolution with 16:10 aspect ratio) and system will ignore top 74 pixels.
I'm using this for some time and it works perfectly.
It is strange that macrumors post where I found this solution seems to be deleted.

Comment: Note that `SwitchResX` is not free.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to write any script or use any program which is not free.

It turned out we can just use [RDM](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM), an app that comes from the hackintosh community.

It is 100% free of charge and contains preset HIDPI resolution settings. You only need to select 1800 * 1125 (HIDPI) for 14-inch models, for a 16-inch device the procedure is similar.

After switching the resolution you can close, or even remove RDM, your changes to the resolution will be kept.

[Download links](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM/issues/55) for the latest version compiled as a universal binary are available.

Comment: Firstly, to describe something as coming from a 'jailbreak community' does not inspire confidence. I was not aware macOS needed a 'jailbreak'... Secondly, the last commit on this project is 2016. Thirdly, the unsigned Apple Silicon builds linked by the linked issue are not official releases by the project, but hosted by third parties with who knows what modifications to the source done in the meantime. Be very wary of going anywhere near this. However if you're prepared to build it yourself, good luck.

Comment: @Andy Griffiths Sorry for the mistake, I was meant to say "hackintosh community".

I've recompiled it for arm64 and it solved my issue with the notch, but I do agree that security issue is what we should be aware of when using unofficial builds.

Answer (score 1):

I made an app that does exactly what you want. You can search "Say No to Notch" on the App Store.